# Как получить индекс элемента последовательности по индексу общих срезов?

Tags: c++

Надумал написать итератор с возможностью изменения режима обхода непрерывной последовательности. То есть, я устанавливаю режим, передавая в соответствующий метод срез(`std::gslicе`, считаю так удобно) который принимает три аргумента:  стартовый индекс и два объекта `std::valarray<size_t>`, представляющие **размеры и шаги** срезов соответственно. Для этого я написал базовый класс, который хранит некоторые данные, и, помимо других услуг, умеет выдать индекс элемента последовательности по индексу общих срезов(именно в реализации этого метода возникла трудность). Вот базовый класс с неправильной реализацией функции_члена `get_slice_index`:

```
class Base_matrix_iterator {    
private:
    const std::valarray<size_t>  sizes,  strides;
        //...
protected:
    size_t curr;
    const size_t start;
    //получить индекс элементa последовательности по индексу срезов
    size_t get_slice_index(size_t n) {
        //неправильный код              
        const size_t
            sz = sizes.size(),
            x = sizes[sz - 2],
            y = sizes[sz - 1],
            z = x * y;
        size_t pos = start;
            
        if (sz == 3 && n >= z) {
            pos += strides[0] * (n / z);
            n %= z;
        }
        if (n >= y) {
            pos += strides[sz - 2] * n / y;
            n %= y;
        }       
        else 
           pos += n * strides[sz - 1];
        return pos;         
    }
        
    //...
        
public:  
    /*ожидается общий срез с двумерными или трехмерными размерами, предназначенные
    для двухмерной и трехмерной матрицы соответственно
    std::gslice(старт, {количество строк, столбцов }, {шаг строк, столбцов})
    Если количество и шаги заданы как std::valarray<size_t>(3),
    то первые аргументы это количество таких матриц и шаги соответственно*/

    Base_matrix_iterator(const std::gslice& s)
        : sizes(s.size()), strides(s.stride()),
        start(s.start()), curr(0) {}
    size_t get_index() { return get_slice_index(curr); }
    //в дальнейшем конструктор и get_index будут
    //в защищенной части, поскольку они нужны только итераторам
    Base_matrix_iterator& operator++()
    {
        ++curr;
        return *this;
    }
    Base_matrix_iterator& operator +(const int off) {/*... */ }
    //наследник будет реализовать Tp& operator *() { return array[get_slice_index(curr)]; } и т.д.
    //...
};
```

Это означает, что:

```
Base_matrix_iterator It({ 0, {3, 2, 4}, {1, 10, 2} }),
    
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        cout << It.get_index() << ' ';
        ++It;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

должен выдать:

```
0 2 4 6     //старт==0 и 4 элемента (шаг == 2)
10 12 14 16  //вторая последовательность шаг == 10 от старта 
1 3 5 7     //и таких (матриц) 3 штуки, ( шаг== 1)
11 13 15 17
2 4 6 8
12 14 16 18
```

а следующий код:

```
Base_matrix_iterator  Iter2({ 1,{2, 3}, {7, 1} });
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    cout << '\n';
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        cout << Iter2.get_index() << ' ';
        ++Iter2;
    }
}
```

должен выдать две последовательности по 3 элемента в каждой:

```
1 2 3   // старт== 1 и 3 элемента (шаг == 1)
8 9 10   //вторая последовательность шаг == 7 от старта
```

Мой код выдает:

```
0 2 4 6
10 12 15 17
1 3 5 7
11 13 16 18
2 4 6 8
12 14 17 19
```

и

```
1 2 3
8 10 12
```

соответственно.

У меня что то заклинило, и я не могу разобраться  в чем ошибка в реализации метода `get_slice_index`.

И, **необязательный** вопрос:
"Не изобретаю ли я велосипед?.."

**P.S.** чтобы было понятно, еще раз про `std::gslice`

Cрез  `std::gslice(start, {x, y}, {sx, sy})` описывает   матрицу размером[x][y] элементов массива `array`:

- array[start ], array[start + sy], array[start + 2sy]... array[start +
  (y - 1) * sy]
- еще таких же `x - 1` последовательностей, только стартом теперь является   `start + i * sx`,
  где `0 < i < x` есть индекс строки, но .

Cрез  `std::gslice(start, {z, x, y}, {sz, sx, sy})` описывает `z` штук таких  матриц(трехмерную матрицу), только `start == start + j`, где `0 <= j < z` есть номер(индекс) матрицы. Словами, это `z` матриц шагом `sz` от начала матрицы, в каждой из них `x` строк, шагом `sx` от начала строк, в каждой строке  `sy` элементов, шагом `sy` от начала строки

Я лишь хочу вычислить индекс элемента массива `array` по индексу полученной двумерной или трехмерной  матрицы из его же элементов.

Comment: https://vk.com/@e_2718281828459045-pravila-oformleniya-koda-na-c

Comment: @timur Вы это к чему? Там много субъективных и спорных правил.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, когда много читаешь и не понимаешь, появляются сомнения. Вот Тимур и попал в такую ситуацию

Comment: Что-то я так и не понял, почему такие последовательности? Может как-то изменить интерфейс или описание, что и для чего делается?

Comment: @avp, для того, чтобы при инкременте итератора  получать не следующий элемент, а  элемент с индексом, выданной функцией. Конкретно для матричного класса, я такой итератор хочу использовать.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, я правильно понимаю, что матрица в памяти представлена непрерывным одномерным массивом, индексы которого выдает итератор, а также, что при создании итератора мы задаем количество строк и столбцов матрицы? (да, я понимаю, что аналогично можно описывать и 3-D матрицу). Но, похоже, я не въезжаю, как задается правило выбора следующего элемента. Следовательно, не могу найти ошибку в ваших вычислениях

Comment: Какую фигуру вы хотите получать, выбирая данные по итератору? Давайте, для простоты для 2-D матрицы. В общем случае это сетка параллелограма, находящегося внутри матрицы. Для нее (кроме размера матрицы) надо задать 4 угла и шаг. (да, в общем случае надо задавать разные шаги по столбцам и строкам) (и конечно, это не совсем общий случай, поскольку шаги константны)  / Вы же задаете 2 величины и я не понимаю их физического смысла

Comment: @avp, для простоты  я могу  матрицу  обойти  не только по очереди с каким то шагом, но  намного большим количеством способов, чем  просто  брать какую то сетку параллелограма, и  чем больше матрица, тем больше раз увеличивается число выбора  способов прохода.  Строку или матрицу из двух строк по 3 элемента`"abc def"` можно обойти например так: `ab de   bc ef `  или  `ace bdf ` или  `abcd bcde cdef ` ну  и т.д., Для матрицы с двенадцатью строками, например,  Можно взять первую строку потом третью, а потом вторую и четвертую, потом девятую и одиннадцатую, десятую и двенадцатую,

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, да, можно придумать много вариантов. но как именно должен работать предлагаемый вами в тексте вопроса я не понимаю

Comment: @avp, да, действительно, я не умею хорошо объяснять _ это есть неоспоримый факт. Но я попытался еще раз _ обновил вопрос. Если у вас есть возможность, помогите пожалуйста, потому что я никак не могу найти причину получения неправильного результата, и  это меня бесит сильно....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, спасибо, теперь (после дополнения в тексте вопроса) кажется понял. Будет время, постараюсь помочь найти ошибку

Comment: А вы пробовали написать тесты и пройти в отладчике?

Comment: @user1056837, да, но так и не понял где ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка кроется в тонкостях:

1. Когда выполняешь несколько действий в одном выражении, нужно не
   забывать о необходимых скобках. В выражении   `pos += strides[sz - 2] * n / y;` я просто забыл скобки ставить вокруг `n / y`, поскольку
   сначала нужно знать на сколько раз n > y, а потом умножить на шаг
   среза.
2. Дальше: поскольку, после взятия остатка `n %= y;`, `n` чаще будет
   иметь не нулевое значение, и нужно выполнить  увеличение   `pos += n * strides[sz - 1];` тоже, то нужно `else` заменить на  `if(n < y)`  или в теле `if (n >= y)` добавить в конце эту операцию.

В итоге правильным кодом будет:

```
size_t get_slice_index(size_t n) {
    const size_t
        sz = sizes.size(),
        x = sizes[sz - 2],
        y = sizes[sz - 1],
        z = x * y;
    size_t pos = start;
        
    if (sz == 3 && n >= z) {
        pos += strides[0] * (n / z);
        n %= z;
    }       
    if (n >= y) {
        pos += strides[sz - 2] * (n / y);
        n %= y;
    }       
    if(n && n < y)
       pos += n * strides[sz - 1];
    return pos;         
}
```

Comment: Только зашел, чтобы поискать, а вы уже сами справились! imho лучше весь правильный код где-то в одном месте разместить, чтобы люди не прыгали вверх-вниз по странице. И заодно подумать про поведение итератора при "лишних" вызовах (это то, что вы хотели? Все же вся информация о размерах матрицы у итератора есть)

Comment: @avp, да, сегодня решил еще раз подумать и  разобрался, . На счет остального, все еще будет не раз изменено и доработано, спасибо вам.